# "AttributeError: module 'bezier' has no attribute 'Curve' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, bezier

I am following the `bezier` [PyPi documentation](https://pypi.org/project/bezier/) in the website and i keep getting this error eventhough  i have already install the module. im running the program on Mac OS Catalina and the python version is Python 3.7.4

here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import bezier

nodes1 = np.asfortranarray([
[0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
[0.0, 1.0, 0.0]])

curve1 = bezier.Curve(nodes1, degree=2)
```

and this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "bezier_2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import bezier
  File "/bezier/bezier.py", line 10, in <module>
    curve1 = bezier.Curve(nodes1, degree=2)
AttributeError: module 'bezier' has no attribute 'Curve'
```

Comment: You can reduce this code to less than 10 lines, so I'd strongly recommend forming a [mcve] in the future. With that said, which version of `bezier` did you install?

Comment: Looks like it should be `bezier.curve.Curve`

Comment: it should not: if I copy the reduced code after installing `bezier` using pipenv, this code runs without any errors. Adding a `print(curve1)` as last line yields `<Curve (degree=2, dimension=2)>` so this might simply be a matter of something not being installed, or invoked, properly.

Comment: My bet is that you called your function bezier.py, 
so `import bezier` does not import the package you intended to import, but imports the current function...